# Is there a map that maps the mean vector and the variance matrix of a multivariate lognormal to its location vector and diffusion matrix?

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, matlab, matrix-decomposition

Suppose ${\xi} \sim logNormal_d ({\mu},{\Sigma})$, where $\mu$ is a d-dimensional vector (called location vector) and $\Sigma$  is a $d \times d$ symmetric positive definite matrix (called diffusion matrix).
Then $$m=E(\xi)=e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} diag(\Sigma)}$$ where $diag(\Sigma) = [\sigma_{1,1},\sigma_{2,2},\ldots,\sigma_{d,d}]'$ and $Var(\xi) = V$ with elements $$v_{i,j} = e^{\mu_1 + \mu_2 +\frac{\sigma_{i,i}+\sigma{j,j}}{2}}\left(e^{\sigma_{i,j}}-1\right).$$

The transformation $(m,V)\mapsto(\mu,\Sigma)$ is defined by the equations:
$$\begin{aligned} \mu= & \log \left( m\oslash\sqrt{1+diag(V)\oslash(m\odot m})\right) \\ 
\Sigma = & \log \left(1+V\oslash\left( m\cdot m'\right) \right),
\end{aligned} $$
where $\odot$  is the element-by-element product and $\oslash$ is the element-by-element division.

I am quite sure of the correctness of this transformation but the simple Matlab code I wrote to implement it, when using a general SPD matrix V as input, returns a $\Sigma$ matrix that is symmetric but not not PD. Is this due to some "computational" error (e.g. rounding or something like that)? Or simply the transformation I found does not guarantee positive-definitness of the $\Sigma$ matrix?

Does anybody know something about a transormation $(m,V)\mapsto(\mu,\Sigma)$ (and maybe a matlab code to implement it...) that guarantees the positive definitness of the matrix $\Sigma$?

Thanks,

Nicola

Comment: You could probably get more help if you edit your question in a more structured format ( e.g. a) Your problem setting, b) What issues you have, and c) If you have tried something) than writing long paragraphs.

Comment: Question edited as suggested!

Comment: Where did you get that transformation from? Does the field exhibit stationarity or in other words the variances of blocks of data should be constant. It'll be positive definite if it's stationary.

Comment: I get the transformation simply solving for $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_{ij}$ the system $$\begin{aligned} m_i = & e^{ \mu_i + \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{ii} } \\ 
v_{ij} = & e^{\mu_i  + \mu_j + \frac{\sigma_{ii}  + \sigma_{jj} }{2} } \left( e^{ \sigma_{ij} } - 1 \right)
\end{aligned} \\ \forall i=1, \ldots, d \quad and \quad j=1,\ldots,i $$

Comment: I believe since you're transforming from one standard distribution to another standard distribution so that should be fine. Maybe either you're 1) missing log while transforming. Sometimes the distribution you have is normal so make sure you're taking care of transforming it to log normal first by taking log. 2) it could also be an error in coding somewhere.

Comment: For the rest I am not sure I get what you mean in the second part of your previous comment. I have got a 10 dimensional vector $\xi = \left[ \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_{10} \right]$ distributed as a multivariate lognormal: what do you mean with "variances of blocks of data"? If you refer to the variance matrices of the couples $\left( \xi_i \xi_j \right)$ they surely are not equal for all i,j: the covariance matrix of the vector $\xi$ is completly general.

Comment: If the covariance is standard then it'll have sill, hence, it'll be positive definite. However, if you're numerical covariance does not have a sill then it's not positive definite. It's the same thing I believe as stationarity

Comment: the matlab code for the transformation is really very simple:  `function [mu, Sigma] = LN2N(m, V)            mu = log(m ./ sqrt(1 + diag(V) ./ (m .^ 2)));
Sigma = log(1 + V ./ (m * m'));` I doubt it can be wrong...

Comment: Moreover, what is sill? In any case the numerical covariance V is SPD (the matlab command chol(V) works and min(eig(V)) is bigger than 0).

Comment: Nicola: To clarify my few "side comments" that I gave earlier, I would like to make two points. 1) not all covariance matrix you obtain numerically will have the property of "covariance" or "correlation" matrix, which is that the covariance matrix is supposed to be positive semi-definite and not all estimates are guaranteed to have that property. 2) I checked if the transformation is PD provided it was PD before, however, I could not find any simple explanation for that.

Comment: I would suggest you could do this to make sure the resultant transformation is correct: Sample some data from the known mean and std dev of the obtained lognormal transformation. Take log of those data and check if their distribution is normal or not. if your transformed lognormal distribution is correct then the log of those data should give you a normal distribution.

Comment: Also, check [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25377/problem-with-negative-values-when-simulating-multivariate-data-using-rmvnorm) just in case it is useful to you.

Comment: Pupil: 1) I am aware that not all "covariance" matrices obtained numerically are symmetric and positive definite (SPD), but that is not my case (I checked the symmetry and the positive definiteness of my input matrices in all the trials I made) 2) As far as I know, there is no direct way sample lognormal data with given mean-vector and variance-matrix (that is exactly what I am looking for!) but only with given location-vector and diffusion-matrix (that are the mean-vector and variance-matrix of the transformed normal). And, since my transformation does not work, I cannot do what you suggest.

Comment: Further, thanks for the link, but in that post they didn't even know of a transformation like the one I presented in my question and, in the last post, is said exactly that they do not know of a way to sample from a multivariate lognormal distribution with given mean-vector and covariance-matrix

Comment: But maybe I found a possible solution (i.e. an alternative transformation that should guarantee symmetry and positive definiteness of the transformed matrix) searching the Web... I'll study it asap (and I'll report the results!)

Comment: Good that you found a potential solution.

Comment: Sorry for being away for so long... The solution I thought I found didn't work.

Comment: I suspect that not every couple made of a $d$-dimensional vector and a $d \times d$ spd matrix can be used as mean vector and covariance matrix for a $d$-dimensional log-normal distribution. Anyone can confirm (or confute!) this?